# Rust: sqlx try_from Option<Uuid>

Tags: rust, rust-sqlx

I have the following code:

```
    // cargo.toml:
    // serde = { version = "1.0", features = ["derive"] }
    // uuid = { version = "1.2", features = ["serde", "v4"] }
    // sqlx = { version = "0.6.2", features = ["runtime-async-std-native-tls", "sqlite", "postgres", "chrono", "uuid", "macros"]}

    use uuid::{Uuid, fmt::Hyphenated};
    use serde::{Deserialize, Serialize};
    
    #[derive(Debug, Serialize, Deserialize, FromRow, PartialEq)]
    pub struct Transaction {
      #[sqlx(try_from = "Hyphenated")]
      pub t_id: Uuid,
      #[sqlx(try_from = "Option<Hyphenated>")]
      pub corr_id: Option<Uuid>,
    }
```

In SQLite database, id stored in hyphenated format like "550e8400-e29b-41d4-a716-446655440000". t_id not null, corr_id nullable.
macro `#[sqlx(try_from = "Hyphenated")]` works fine, but I cant figure out, how to use it with Option for corr_id field. Given code panics. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The compiler tells us that it cannot implicitly convert `Hyphenated` to an `Option<Uuid>`,

```rust
| #[derive(Debug, Serialize, Deserialize, FromRow, PartialEq)]
|                                         ^^^^^^^ the trait `From<Hyphenated>` is not implemented for `std::option::Option<Uuid>`
```

and we can't [implement external traits for external types](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch10-02-traits.html#implementing-a-trait-on-a-type). The only choices left seem to be

#### 1. Implement the `FromRow` trait yourself

Since we know that we'll be using SQLite and the `corr_id` is a nullable text column, we can implement `FromRow` for `sqlx::sqlite::SqliteRow`s. If your struct (row) only has these two fields, this is fine but when extending it with additional fields, you'll need to update your `FromRow` implementation as well.

```rust
use sqlx::{sqlite::SqliteRow, FromRow, Row};
use uuid::{fmt::Hyphenated, Uuid};

pub struct Transaction {
    pub t_id: Uuid,
    pub corr_id: Option<Uuid>,
}

impl<'r> FromRow<'r, SqliteRow> for Transaction {
    fn from_row(row: &'r SqliteRow) -> Result<Self, sqlx::Error> {
        let t_id: Hyphenated = row.try_get("t_id")?;
        let corr_id: &str = row.try_get("corr_id")?;
        let corr_id = if corr_id.is_empty() {
            None
        } else {
            let uuid = Uuid::try_parse(&corr_id).map_err(|e| sqlx::Error::ColumnDecode {
                index: "corr_id".to_owned(),
                source: Box::new(e),
            })?;
            Some(uuid)
        };
        Ok(Transaction {
            t_id: t_id.into(),
            corr_id,
        })
    }
}
```

#### 2. Use a [newtype](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch19-03-advanced-traits.html#using-the-newtype-pattern-to-implement-external-traits-on-external-types)

This way, you can reuse your "nullable" type in other structs if necessary, and can even implement [`Deref`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Deref.html), if you want to make extracting the inner UUID easier. It does come with some extra allocations though, since the incoming bytes are converted first to `String`, then parsed into `Uuid`.

```rust
use std::ops::Deref;
use sqlx::FromRow;

#[derive(FromRow)]
pub struct Transaction {
    #[sqlx(try_from = "Hyphenated")]
    pub t_id: Uuid,
    #[sqlx(try_from = "String")]
    pub corr_id: NullableUuid,
}

pub struct NullableUuid(Option<Uuid>);

impl TryFrom<String> for NullableUuid {
    type Error = uuid::Error;

    fn try_from(value: String) -> Result<Self, Self::Error> {
        let inner = if value.is_empty() {
            None
        } else {
            let uuid = Uuid::try_parse(&value)?;
            Some(uuid)
        };
        Ok(NullableUuid(inner))
    }
}

impl Deref for NullableUuid {
    type Target = Option<Uuid>;

    fn deref(&self) -> &Self::Target {
        &self.0
    }
}
```

Comment: Peter, Thanks a lot! With little adjustments both of your suggestions works! I choose approach with new type. It was unhappy giving error 
`the trait bound NullableUuid: From<std::option::Option<_>> is not satisfied
required for std::option::Option<_> to implement Into<NullableUuid>`
Fixed with 
`impl From<Option<Uuid>> for NullableUuid {
            fn from(value: Option<Uuid>) -> Self {
                Self(value)
            }
        }
`
Thanks also to chatGPT for this suggestion.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, I fixed the example so it actually compiles now (without needing `From`)